# find point where barycentric weights have a specific value

Tags: geometry

I have triangle: `a`, `b`, `c`. Each vertex has a value: `va`, `vb`, `vc`. In my software the user drags point `p` around inside and outside of this triangle. I use barycentric coordinates to determine the value `vp` at `p` based on `va`, `vb`, and `vc`. So far, so good.

Now I want to limit `p` so that `vp` is within range `min` and `max`. If a user chooses `p` where `vp` is < `min` or > `max`, how can I find the point closest to `p` where `vp` is equal to `min` or `max`, respectively?

**Edit:** Here is an example where I test each point. Light gray is within `min`/`max`. How can I find the equations of the lines that make up the `min`/`max` boundary?

[image: example]

```
a = 200, 180
b = 300, 220
c = 300, 300
va = 1
vb = 1.4
vc = 3.2
min = 0.5
max = 3.5
```

**Edit:** FWIW, so far first I get the barycentric coordinates `v`,`w` for `p` using the triangle vertices `a`, `b`, `c` (standard stuff I think, but looks like [this](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/math/GeometryUtils.java#L36)). Then to get `vp`:

```
u = 1 - w - v
vp = va * u + vb * w + vc * v
```

That is all fine. My trouble is that I need the line equations for `min`/`max` so I can choose a new position for `p` when `vp` is out of range. The new position for `p` is the point closest to `p` on the min or max line.

Note that `p` is an XY coordinate and `vp` is a value for that coordinate determined by the triangle and the values at each vertex. `min` and `max` are also values. The two line equations I need will give me XY coordinates for which the values determined by the triangle are `min` or `max`.

It doesn't matter if barycentric coordinates are used in the solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The trick is to use the ratio of value to cartesian distance to extend each triangle edge until it hits min or max. Easier to see with a pic:

[image]

The cyan lines show how the triangle edges are extended, the green Xs are points on the min or max lines. With just 2 of these points we know the slope if the line. The yellow lines show connecting the Xs aligns with the light gray.

The math works like this, first get the value distance between vb and vc:
valueDistBtoC = vc - vb

Then get the cartesian distance from b to c:
cartesianDistBtoC = b.distance(c)

Then get the value distance from b to max:
valueDistBtoMax = max - vb

Now we can cross multiply to get the cartesian distance from b to max:
cartesianDistBtoMax = (valueDistBtoMax * cartesianDistBtoC) / valueDistBtoC

Do the same for min and also for a,b and c,a. The 6 points are enough to restrict the position of p.

Answer (score 4):

Consider your triangle to actually be a 3D triangle, with points `(ax,ay,va)`, `(bx,by,vb)`, and `(cx,cy,vc)`. These three points define a plane, containing all the possible `p,vp` triplets obtainable through barycentric interpolation.

Now think of your constraints as two other planes, at `z>=max` and `z<=min`. Each of these planes intersects your triangle's plane along an infinite line; the infinite beam between them, projected back down onto the xy plane, represents the area of points which satisfy the constraints. Once you have the lines (projected down), you can just find which (if either) is violated by a particular point, and move it onto that constraint (along a vector which is perpendicular to the constraint).

Now I'm not sure about your hexagon, though. That's not the shape I would expect.

Comment: Your way of thinking about it in 3D seems like it may be correct, but is difficult to translate the solution to code. I've updated the question with a possible lead on a solution. I'd be very interested to hear your thoughts on it. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Mathematically speaking the problem is simply a change of coordinates. The more difficult part is finding a good notation for the quantities involved.

You have two systems of coordinates: (x,y) are the cartesian coordinates of your display and (v,w) are the baricentric coordinates with respect to the vectors (c-a),(b-a) which determine another (non orthogonal) system.

What you need is to find the equation of the two lines in the (x,y) system, then it will be easy to project the point p on these lines.

To achieve this you could explicitly find the matrix to pass from (x,y) coordinates to (v,w) coordinates and back. The function you are using `toBaryCoords` makes this computation to find the coordinates (v,w) from (x,y) and we can reuse that function.
We want to find the coefficients of the transformation from *world* coordinates (x,y) to *barycentric* coordinates (v,w). It must be in the form

v = O_v + x_v * x + y_v * y

w = O_w + x_w * x + y_w * y

i.e.

(v,w) = (O_v,O_w) + (x_v,y_y) * (x,y)

and you can determine (O_v,O_w) by computing toBaryCoord(0,0), then find (x_v,x_w) by computing the coordinates of (1,0) and find (y_v,y_w)=toBaryCoord(1,0) - (O_v,O_w) and then find (y_v,y_w) by computing (y_v,y_w) = toBaryCoord(0,1)-(O_v,O_w).

This computation requires calling toBaryCoord three times, but actually the coefficients are computed inside that routine every time, so you could modify it to compute at once all six values.

The value of your function vp can be computed as follows. I will use f instead of v because we are using v for a baricenter coordinate. Hence in the following I mean f(x,y) = vp, fa = va, fb = vb, fc = vc.

You have:

f(v,w) = fa + (fb-fa)*v + (fc-fa)*w

i.e.

f(x,y) = fa + (fb-fa) (O_v + x_v * x + y_v * y) + (fc-fa) (O_w + x_w * x + y_w * y)

where (x,y) are the coordinates of your point p. You can check the validity of this equation by inserting the coordinates of the three vertices a, b, c and verify that you obtain the three values fa, fb and fc. Remember that the barycenter coordinates of a are (0,0) hence O_v + x_v * a_x + y_v * a_y = 0 and so on... (a_x and a_y are the x,y coordinates of the point a).

If you let

q = fa + (fb_fa)*O_v + (fc-fa)*O_w

fx = (fb-fa)*x_v + (fc-fa) * x_w

fy = (fb-fa)*y_v + (fc-fa) * y_w

you get

f(x,y) = q + fx*x + fy * y

Notice that q, fx and fy can be computed once from a,b,c,fa,fb,fc and you can reuse them if you only change the coordinates (x,y) of the point p.

Now if f(x,y)>max, you can easily project (x,y) on the line where max is achieved. The coordinates of the projection are:

(x',y') = (x,y) - [(x,y) * (fx,fy) - max + q]/[(fx,fy) * (fx,fy)] (fx,fy)

Now. You would like to **have the code**. Well here is some *pseudo*-code:

```
toBarycoord(Vector2(0,0),a,b,c,O);
toBarycoord(Vector2(1,0),a,b,c,X);
toBarycoord(Vector2(0,1),a,b,c,Y);
X.sub(O); // X = X - O
Y.sub(O); // Y = Y - O

V = Vector2(fb-fa,fc-fa);

q =  fa + V.dot(O); // q = fa + V*O
N = Vector2(V.dot(X),V.dot(Y)); // N = (V*X,V*Y)

// p is the point to be considered

f = q + N.dot(p); // f = q + N*p

if (f > max) {
  Vector2 tmp;
  tmp.set(N);
  tmp.multiply((N.dot(p) - max + q)/(N.dot(N))); // scalar multiplication
  p.sub(tmp);
}

if (f < min) {
  Vector2 tmp;
  tmp.set(N);
  tmp.multiply((N.dot(p) - min + q)/(N.dot(N))); // scalar multiplication
  p.sum(tmp);
}
```

Comment: This looks great, so you got the 500 rep bounty. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

We think of the problem as follows: The three points are interpreted as a triangle floating in 3D space with the value being the Z-axis and the cartesian coordinates mapped to the X- and Y- axes respectively.

Then the question is to find the gradient of the plane that is defined by the three points. The lines where the plane intersects with the `z = min` and `z = max` planes are the lines you  want to restrict your points to.

If you have found a point p where v(p) > max or v(p) < min we need to go in the direction of the steepest slope (the gradient) until `v(p + k * g) = max` or min respectively. `g` is the direction of the gradient and `k` is the factor we need to find. The coordinates you are looking for (in the cartesian coordinates) are the corresponding components of `p + k * g`.

In order to determine `g` we calculate the orthonormal vector that is perpendicular to the plane that is determined by the three points using the cross product:

```
// input:  px, py, pz, 
// output: p2x, p2y

// local variables
var v1x, v1y, v1z, v2x, v2y, v2z, nx, ny, nz, tp, k,

// two vectors pointing from b to a and c respectively
v1x = ax - bx;
v1y = ay - by;
v1z = az - bz;

v2x = cx - bx;
v2y = cy - by;
v2z = cz - bz;

// the cross poduct
nx = v2y * v1z - v2z * v1y;
ny = v2z * v1x - v2x * v1z;
nz = v2x * v1y - v2y * v1x;

// using the right triangle altitude theorem
// we can calculate the vector that is perpendicular to n
// in our triangle we are looking for q where p is nz, and h is sqrt(nx*nx+ny*ny)
// the theorem says p*q = h^2 so p = h^2 / q  - we use tp to disambiguate with the point p - we need to negate the value as it points into the opposite Z direction
tp = -(nx*nx + ny*ny) / nz;

// now our vector g = (nx, ny, tp) points into the direction of the steepest slope 
// and thus is perpendicular to the bounding lines

// given a point p (px, py, pz) we can now calculate the nearest point p2 (p2x, p2y, p2z) where min <= v(p2z) <= max

if (pz > max){
  // find k
  k = (max - pz) / tp;
  p2x = px + k * nx;
  p2y = py + k * ny;
  // proof: p2z = v = pz + k * tp = pz + ((max - pz) / tp) * tp = pz + max - pz = max
} else if (pz < min){
  // find k
  k = (min - pz) / tp;
  p2x = px + k * nx;
  p2y = py + k * ny;
} else {
  // already fits
  p2x = px;
  p2y = py;
}
```

Note that obviously if the triangle is vertically oriented (in 2D it's not a triangle anymore actually), `nz` becomes zero and `tp` cannot be calculated. That's because there are no more two lines where the value is min or max respectively. For this case you will have to choose another value on the remaining line or point.